# Error casting ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I need to pass to a secondary activity an object defined as:

```
public class Campionati extends ArrayList<Campionato> implements Serializable {
```

I'm able to create an extra containing the object. 
In the onCreate() function of the secondary activity I go to retrieve the data by the code:

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (b!=null) {
        Serializable s = b.getSerializable("datiSport");
        Campionati m_campionati = (Campionati)s;
```

Both b and s objects are good and s is typed as ArrayList. 
The last command generates an exception:

Java.lang.ClassCastException: Java.util.ArrayList

What does it mean?
 I don't understand why the cast is not possible .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does it mean? I don't understand why the cast is not possible .

It means that the object in question is an `ArrayList` of some kind, not a `Campionati`.

Your inheritance relationship means that any `Campionati` can be treated as an `ArrayList` - but the reverse is *not* true. You can only cast to `Campionati` if the object in question is *actually* an instance of `Campionati` or a subclass.